# Не всегда работает перемотка audio в разных браузерах

Tags: html5, аудио

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь сделать проигрывание аудиофайла на странице. Мне обязательно нужна перемотка файла, но я столкнулся со странным поведением этой перемотки.
В firefox перемотка аудиофайла в теге  работает для всех файлов.
В yandex.browser - не для всех.
В chrome перемотка audio заработала только для ogg, и то, для одного.

Пробовал разные форматы - то перематывается, то не перематывается. 
Я думал, что дело в том, как я пишу тэг аудио, но когда я щелкаю по ссылке на файл, то страницу с плеером создает сам браузер (все три браузера так себя ведут).
Проигрывают файл без проблем, пауза работает, но вот перейти к произвольному моменту файла я не могу.

Вот файл, у которого перемотка не работает в Я.Браузере и хроме, но работает в FF:
[перемотка только в FF](http://185.81.113.177/media/1.mp3)

Вот mp3 файл, у которого работает перемотка в Я.браузере и FF, но не в хроме:
[перемотка в FF и яндекс](http://185.81.113.177/media/1_3.mp3)

Вот ogg файл, у которого перемотка работает в Я.браузере и FF, но не в хроме:
[перемотка в FF и яндекс](http://185.81.113.177/media/1_2_3.ogg)

Вот файл, у которого работает перемотка во всех трех браузерах:
[перемотка везде](http://185.81.113.177/media/1_2.ogg)

Ищу третий день, не могу понять, в чем дело. Пробовал переменный битрейт, постоянный битрейт - и не нашел гарантированного условия работы перемотки.
Мне не обязательно, чтобы во всех браузерах работало и во всех версиях. Достаточно, если под хромом и FF будет.  Ах да, еще сафари, на всякий случай. Но от сафари можно отказаться.

Еще раз подчеркну, что я просто ввожу эту ссылку в адресную строку, а браузер сам открывает. Поначалу я думал, что как-то не так пишу тег audio, что у меня перемотка не работает.

Comment: Ну вот, теперь работает и в хроме все, кроме первого файла. Ничего не  могу понять.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в настройках сервера.
Я отдавал файлы через django и они нормально скачивались.
Хороший человек  (support плеера uppod) проверил мою страницу и сказал, что их неправильно отдает сервер.
Изменил настройки сервера и стал отдавать файлы nginx'ом, а не django - и все заработало.